# Trying to deploy machine learning model on kubernettes, getting failed with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython' or 'setuptools_rust'

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Here is my environment yml file :-

```
# Conda environment specification. The dependencies defined in this file will
# be automatically provisioned for runs with userManagedDependencies=False.
# Details about the Conda environment file format:
# https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually


name: project_environment
dependencies:
  # The python interpreter version.

  # Currently Azure ML only supports 3.5.2 and later.

- python
- pip

- pip:
    # Required packages for AzureML execution, history, and data preparation.

  - azureml-defaults
  - scikit-learn

  - numpy
  - azureml-monitoring
  - cython
  - setuptools_rust
```

And it is failing on below code:

```
-
deployment_config = AksWebservice.deploy_configuration(auth_enabled=False, collect_model_data=True, enable_app_insights=True, cpu_cores = 2, memory_gb = 2)
aks_target = AksCompute(ws,aks_name)
(On below line getting error)
service = Model.deploy(ws, service_name, [model], inference_config, deployment_config, aks_target)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output = True)
```

Comment: Please write in a style that is easier to read. If you just need to list the contents of your environment.yml file you can get rid of the big titles. You can also use code formatting (button with the "{}" when you are editing) to make the code at the end of your question easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue happened when the setuptools is not installed or not installed in the same path. Your setup.py file needs setuptools. Uninstall and install may help, it fix my issue.

```
pip uninstall setuptools
```

and then:

```
pip install setuptools
```

Also, sometimes pip version can cause this issue as well.

```
pip3 install -U pip
```